# How to calculate RPM from a square wave signal Voltage-Time graph

Tags: voltage, hall-effect, rpm

I'm struggling to understand how to show the relationship between the input and output of a hall effect sensor used as a wheel speed sensor through mathematical expression. How can I calculate the RPM if the input gives me a square wave signal? I understand it may be through calculating the frequency, but I feel like I'm missing something.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Hook up a voltmeter to the sensor.
2. Turn the wheel by hand one full revolution while counting the number of positive-going pulses generated. Call that ***n***.
3. Measure the periodic time of the squarewave from your graph. Call that ***t***. (It's 10 ms in the graph in your question.)

$$ RPM = 60 \times rps = 60 \frac 1 t \frac 1 n $$
where *rps* = revolutions per second.

$$ RPM = \frac {60}{tn} $$